# What do the double curly braces in Flask mean when surrounding a function?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

This program has
"  {{ super() }}  "
in the code and I don't understand what it means. Is this javascript function or a flask function or am I wrong and it's variable? The '()' is throwing me off, what language is the stuff inside of the double curly braces?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

The {{ super() }} block is a function that is referring to the code written in the parent's file. You use this function when you are inheriting from an html file and you want to write the code written in the parent.
It's a Python function, a special syntax from flask and jinja2